# Get deleted object with paranoid through related activerecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, acts-as-paranoid

I have 3 models:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :offer
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cruise, inverse_of: :offers
  has_many :requests
end

class Travel < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid    
  has_many :offers, inverse_of: :travel
end
```

Usually I can access `Travel` object through chain like this: `request.offer.travel`.

However, if `Travel` object I need is deleted with `paranoia` - I can not access it through such objects chain.

`Travel.with_deleted.find(some_id_of_deleted_travel)` works perfectly, but `request.offers.travel.with_deleted`, that the same object, throws me `undefined method 'with_deleted' for nil:NilClass`.

How can I access deleted object through relation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer, however, I'm not satisfied with it.

It order to get associated object that was soft deleted, I have to modify `Offer` model like this and unscope relation:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cruise, inverse_of: :offers
  has_many :requests

  def travel
    Travel.unscoped { super }
  end
end
```

In my case this works, but breaks some functionality, cause I need to unscope relation only in this very situation, leaving other cases untouched. It would be nice to have something like `request.offers.travel(:unscoped)` etc.

In my case best solution was simply access this object separately like `Travel.with_deleted.find(@offer.travel_id)`

Answer (score 1):

On Rails > 4. You can use the unscope method for remove the paranoid scope.

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :offer, -> { unscope(where: :deleted_at) }
end
```